# Firebase firestore get user document without authenticated

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I was trying to build an application in flutter with firebase. I don't want to User to authenticate him/her to firebase authentication.

All I want them to use their phone number as a secret code. Meaning he/she can enter the  phone number to view their data without authentication. Without phone number, they cannot read the data.(without OTP too).

Now  I have this in firestore rule, so anybody holds the phone number can view the data.

```
 function isUserRef(field) { 
  return field in resource.data
    && resource.data.mobile == /customers/document/$(request.resource.data.mobile)
}

match /customers/{document=**} {
  allow read : if isUserRef(request.resource.data.mobile);
}
```

request resource data contain as below.

```
User{
"id" : null,
"mobile" : "7878445778"
}
```

But the above rule still doesn't match the document based on his/her mobile number. I don't want to user to authenticate at all. It's simple application were data is not a concern.

Any help appreciated!!. Thanks.

Comment: What data are you storing for a user? How do you ensure that other people cannot access their data by giving you their phone number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how your database is set up or how you're passing the phone number, but here's a simpler approach that may help guide you.

Set your database up where the phone number is the customer's ID.  If that's not possible, create a `phoneToCustomers` collection that is used to match phone numbers to customers.

#### Example 1: Phone Numbers as Customer IDs

Let's assume your customer IDs are their phone numbers:

```
{
  "customers": {
    "7878445778": {...},
    "1231231234": {...}
  }
}
```

With this simple rule you can accomplish what you want:

```
match /customers/{phone} {

  // Allow anyone with the phone number to access this document
  allow get: if true;

  // Can't list all customers
  allow list: if false;
}
```

#### Example 2: Customer ID Lookup Table

Let's assume your database looks like this:

```
{
  "customers": {
    "abc123": {...},
    "xyz987": {...}
  },
  "phoneToCustomers": {
    "7878445778": "abc123",
    "1231231234": "xyz987"
  }
}
```

These rules prevent users from querying your customers or phone numbers but allows retrieving documents if the user knows the ID.

```
match /customers/{customerId} {

  // Allow anyone with the customer ID to access this document
  allow get: if true;

  // Can't list all customers
  allow list: if false;
}

match /phoneToCustomers/{phone} {

  // Allow anyone with the phone number to access this document
  allow get: if true;

  // Can't list all customers
  allow list: if false;
}
```

You would then need to get() `/phoneToCustomers/7878445778` to get the customer ID then a second get() to retrieve the customer data at `/customers/<customerId>`.

Comment: Thanks!, BTW this turns my head to the right direction, But I am not sure how to replace the key that holds the data. Meaning User(id:null, mobile:989898989); How do I set the key as the mobile number?.

Comment: Ahh!!, let me try that 1st option and let me know you the result.

Comment: @EngineSense a third option if you can't implement that simple data structure would be to create a Cloud Function that accepts a phone number, queries the database and returns the record.

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate incoming requests against other documents in the database you can use `get()` or `exists()` request, they expect fully specified document path.

Keep in mind, that functions have access to variables, that are defined in the scope where you define them.

**This function checks if document named as users phone number exists:**

```
function isUser(request) { 
  let requestData = request.resource.data.mobile;
  let docExists = exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/customers/$(requestData)); 
return docExists;
```

**This function checks if document has field with users phone number:**

```
function isUser(document, request) {
  let requestData = request.resource.data.mobile;
  let fieldExists = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/customers/$(document)).data.mobile == requestData;
return fieldExists;
```

This usecase as you can see also requires `document` wildcard to be passed to function.

With first function your security rules will be:

```
match /customers/{document} {
  allow read : if isUser(request);
}
```

With second function your security rules will be:

```
match /customers/{document} {
  allow read : if isUser(document, request);
}
```